# Which part of Weil's conjecture fails for a nice singular variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a singular variety defined over $\mathbb{Z}$, for simplicity let's assume that the singularities of $X$ consist of finite number of $\mathbb{Z}$-valued double points. Then good reduction over a prime number $p$ still makes sense, i.e. the singularities of $X \times \mathbb{F}_{p}$ consist of the 'same' $\mathbb{F}_p$-valued double points. ($X$ and $X \times \mathbb{F}_{p}$ have the same type of singularities)

Now if $X$ has good reduction mod $p$, we can count the number of points on the variety $X \times \mathbb{F}_{p}$. My questions are,

1. For a double point of $X$, since it is $\mathbb{Z}$-valued, it induces an $\mathbb{F}_p$-valued double point of $X \times \mathbb{F}_{p}$. Should we take into consideration of the multiplicity (which is 2) of this point in points-counting?
2. Which part of Weil conjectures fails? i.e.

   1). Is the zeta function still a rational function? If so, could it be computed by etale cohomology of $X$ like the smooth case?

   2). If 1). is true, does the zeta function satisfies the usual functional equation?

   3). Is the Riemann hypothesis still true?

Comment: Rationality is true for all $X/\mathbf{F}_q$ of finite type, see e.g. Bjorn Poonen's book.

Comment: See also https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/dworks-proof-of-rationality-of-the-zeta-function-over-finite-fields/

Comment: (The Lefschetz trace formula for seperated varieties is proved in Milne's *Étale cohomology*, Theorem VI.13.1.)

Comment: The functional equation comes from Poincaré duality, so for most singular varieties this is not true. Similarly, the Riemann hypothesis says something about purity of cohomology, which is also false for most singular varieties. However, a weaker statement is still true: the eigenvalues are $q$-Weil numbers, but not of the right weight.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thank you very much

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn : would you have a reference for the fact that eigenvalues of the Frobenius over the $\ell$-adic cohomology of a (possibly singular) projective irreducible variety over $\Bbb F_q$ are $q$-Weil numbers?

Comment: @Watson it follows for example from the main result of Deligne's [Weil II paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1980__52__137_0) (see the first page of the introduction).