# Restrictions on the Galois representations coming from singular varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Fix a prime number $p$. Choose an algebraic closure $\mathbb{Q}_p\to \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. Given a proper geometrically irreducible scheme $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and a non-negative integer $i$, the cohomology group $H^i_{et}(X\times \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}, \mathbb{Q}_p)$ is a finite-dimensional continuous representation of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$. What properties must a finite-dimensional continuous representation of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ satisfy to be realizable this way? I think there is some condition on the eigenvalues of the Frobenius (see [Which part of Weil's conjecture fails for a nice singular variety](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293812/which-part-of-weils-conjecture-fails-for-a-nice-singular-variety#comment729281_293812)) but that is probably not the only condition.

More specifically, is $H^i_{et}(X\times \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}, \mathbb{Q}_p)$ necessarily semisimple? Is it Hodge-Tate? For example, if $X$ is a geometrically unibranch projective curve then it is Hodge-Tate because the normalization map is a universal homeomorphism and $l$-adic cohomology is preserved by universal homeomorphisms.

Comment: For any inverse system of quasi-compact quasi-separated schemes with affine transition morphisms, the cohomology of the limit is equal to the direct limit of cohomology(Corollary 5.8 in SGA 4 Chapter VII). In particular, $H^i_{et}(X\times \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p},\mathbb{Z}/p^n)$ is equal to the direct limit of groups $H^i_{et}(X\times K,\mathbb{Z}/p^n)$ where $K$ ranges over finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: So the stabilizer of any element of the $Z/p^n$-etale cohomology is open in the Galois group, hence the action is continuous for the discrete topology and the action on $H^i_{et}(X\times \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p},\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is continuous for the inverse limit(=p-adic) topology.

Comment: @SashaP thank you. Then is it true that in the statement of etale Ehresmann's theorem if the base is $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Q}_p$ the smoothness hypothesis is not necessary?

Comment: Are you asking about whether the derived pushfrowards from a proper flat family are locally constant? No, that's not true without the smoothness assumption, and that doesn't really have anything to do with the continuity of the Galois action, the latter essentially being a formal statement  as you see.

Comment: @SashaP for $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Q}_p$ an lcc sheaf is the same thing as a continuous $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$-representation. I am asking this specifically when the base is $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Q}_p$ (so any family is automatically flat).

Comment: Sure, if you just have a variety over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ then everything is as you say.

Comment: @SashaP thank you, I will edit the question.

Comment: Do you mean to have the coefficients $\mathbb Q_p$ and the base field be the same? The Weil conjectures are about cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb Q_\ell$ for some $\ell \neq p$, and do indeed have a good generalization to non-smooth (and non-proper) varieties. This is Deligne's "Weil II" result, and is related to the size of Frobenius eigenvalues. When $\ell=p$, the study of $p$-adic Galois representations arising as etale cohomology is the subject of $p$-adic Hodge theory, and the central theorems carry over to the non-smooth case there too.

Comment: @dorebell there is a proof of Weil conjectures using some kind of $p$-adic cohomological arguments (Kedlaya and others) but admittedly I do not know what do their arguments say specifically about $p$-adic etale cohomology. If you know any references about $p$-Hodge theory in the non-smooth case they would be helpful.

Comment: $p$-adic etale cohomology for a variety which is not necessarily smooth or proper is still de Rham and even potentially semistable.  I believe this is due to Tsuji. You can relate it to the log-crystalline cohomology of a model. The Brinon-Conrad notes explain what these conditions mean (and give references for the comparison theorems)